# CTime unknown exception c++

Tags: c++, mfc, atl

I had initialized a Ctime object using its constructor as shown below:

`CTime myTime = CTime( 1956, 12, 12, 4,40,12 );`

But on running the application an unknown exception is thrown.
What is wrong in this case? Please help.

Comment: Did you check the docs for allowed values/ranges?

Comment: Please post a **complete but minimal** example that readers can compile and try out. Note that this is possible even for MFC. You don't have to use the Visual Studio wizards.

Comment: For CTime is there any such range?

Comment: On debugging I found the exception is thrown from this statement.

Answer (score 2):

**[“number of seconds after January 1, 1970”](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6989cds.aspx)** is incompatible with a 1956 date.

*It’s often a good idea to check the documentation before posting.*

Other readers, or googlers who end up here, can/may benefit if you explain why you didn’t check the documentation, or even inspect the exception?

Comment: Sorry for that. No one will think of range for time I guess.

Comment: So how should I use it to set a date before 1970

Comment: @CodeRider: you can't. again, from the documentation, "The upper date limit is 12/31/3000. The lower limit is 1/1/1970 12:00:00 AM GMT." That's it. A pretty unusable time class. Why not use the standard C++ library instead?

Comment: It is quite weird that CTime has this limitation. The SYSTEMTIME structure supports years all the way back to 1601. I don't know how this isn't a bug, given how MFC uses CTime objects as a generic wrapper for SYSTEMTIME.

Comment: The start of epoch stems from **[Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)**, and is reflected also in the C and C++ standard library date and time functions. However, Unix time allows for negative values. There is a problem going backwards to Julian time, because that calendar was phased out at different times in different regions (and at sea), but 1956 is safe at any rate.